# I have an iPad mini 2, with ios 7.2, can i manually upgrade to 8.1.2 and still jailbreak it?

Tags: ios, ipad, upgrade

I just bought my wife an iPad mini 2, ( it was still factory sealed) it has 7.2 on it and I'd  like to know if I can still update it to 8.1.2 and jailbreak it. I know downgrading from 8.1.3 can no longer be done but what about upgrading from older firmware to 8.1.2? It's this still possible even if apple is no longer signing it?

Thanks,

Ocha

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Apple is no longer signing the 8.1.2 update, as can be seen in the chart at [The iPhone Wiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/SHSH).

[image: Screenshot of chart showing dates when Apple was signing the 8.1.2 update]

Edit: The screenshot got partially cut-off, but the upshot is that all devices that support 8.1.2 were listed under the same item, and all stopped signing on 10 February 2015.